# Getting logged out

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts, login

Since the last 2 or 3 weeks, I've been getting logged out of all stackexchange and stackoverflow sites. It started on my iPad and now it's happening on my iMac too. This happens randomly. It just happened a moment ago: I was active in math.stackexchange and when I moved to stackoverflow I had been logged out. I went back to math.stackexchange and saw that I had been logged out there as well.

Is this happening just to me? Can I do something to avoid this annoyance?

BTW, I'm using Safari in all platforms.

EDIT (2015-11-11) This is still happening and it is getting worse in my iPad.
Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: This was happening to me frequently months ago, but now it seems to have abated somewhat. Also only on Safari.

Comment: This has happened to me a number of times but not with great frequency (using Firefox).

Comment: Safari (can't recall if it was phone or laptop) switching to MO, to which I also have an account. Isolated though, *seems* to rarely happen.